# Error using twilio: Type 'com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jsr310/ser/ZoneIdSerializer

Tags: twilio, sms

I'm new using twilio and I'm having a issue, maybe you guys can help.
Everything works fine using twilio when I'm testing the sms sending in my local machine.
But then yesterday my code was deployed to qa staging and it doesn´t work there.

If we check the logs, it logs this:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-27" java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jsr310/JavaTimeModule.<init>()V @283: invokevirtual
  Reason:
    Type 'com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jsr310/ser/ZoneIdSerializer' (current frame, stack[2]) is not assignable to 'com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonSerializer'
  Current Frame:
    bci: @283
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jsr310/JavaTimeModule' }
    stack: { 'com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jsr310/JavaTimeModule', 'java/lang/Class', 'com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jsr310/ser/ZoneIdSerializer' }

at com.twilio.http.TwilioRestClient.<init>(TwilioRestClient.java:52)
        at com.twilio.http.TwilioRestClient$Builder.build(TwilioRestClient.java:145)
        at com.twilio.Twilio.buildRestClient(Twilio.java:202)
        at com.twilio.Twilio.getRestClient(Twilio.java:174)
        at com.twilio.base.Creator.create(Creator.java:40)
        at com.vertrax.wellsite.email.model.TwilioSmsServiceManager.sendSmsNotifications(TwilioSmsServiceManager.java:41)
        at com.vertrax.wellsite.notification.bo.NotificationBO$1.run(NotificationBO.java:363)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

It seems to be something related to jsr310 and specically ZoneIdSerializer.
I'm sorry, I dont have much knowledge about jackson, jsr310, etc.
I dont undertand why it works to me and it's not working in qa environment.
I'm using java 8.

Do you guys have any ideas?
Thank you so much.